# apache2 running but doesnt load my index.html

Tags: apache, linux, apache2

I have a linux server running apache2, I have my own user folder: /home/me/...
I added a .htaccess to my folder with:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

in it and the server IP is:
123.456.789.111

I tried: http://123.456.789.111/index.html

to no avail. I know I probably doing something wrong, I never used apache.

Comment: Can you post a sanitized copy of your httpd.conf?

Comment: isnt /etc/apache2/apache2.conf is what you are looking for? I'm running Ubuntu

Comment: If you are using the default site, your DocRoot will be /var/www by default. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what it is you are trying to do?  Normally, if you start apache up, the default page will be a stick "It works!" page.

Comment: your IP address is funny :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. httpd.conf must have already DirectoryIndex for "Main" site
2. AllowOverrride for `<Directory />` container must not be None in order htaccess directives to work